Move column referenced within formula based on an a changing cell
Hopefully I am overthinking this but I am trying to do the following -
I have pulled the top 10 items sales by code using XLOOKUP and LARGER. I now, based on the sales number pulled, look up the product name associated with that code. The code can changed (it's a drop down list) so I need that column reference to move. All the numbers are being pulled from another sheet which has every code and their sales for all products.
Inputs

Output

So far I tired an XLOOKUP within an XLOOKUP and INDEX/MATCH. I think there's a way to use OFFSET or INDIRECT but so far its spitting out #VALUE or #NA

I can propose you this solution:
[Sheet2!B4] =TAKE(SORT(CHOOSECOLS(Sheet1!A2:E13,1,MATCH(C1,Sheet1!B1:E1,0)+1),2,-1),10)


=TAKE(
  SORT(
    CHOOSECOLS(
      Sheet1!A2:E13,
      1,
      MATCH(C1,Sheet1!B1:E1,0)+1
    ),
    2,
    -1
  )
  ,10
)

Algo:

MATCH determines the sales column number.
CHOOSECOL choses the first and (1) columns.
SORT sorts (2) by the second column, which is the selected sales column, by the descending order.
TAKE takes the first 10 rows from (3).

One formula calculates everything.

I'm not sure whether "inputs" (from the other sheet) is from a query or entered in that sheet. If feasible, I would suggest inserting a table for the "inputs" (adding a name for the item column). With table added,

we could define a name for the code drop-down - for example code_for_summary

Then get the summary with
=TAKE(SORT(
CHOOSECOLS(Table1,XMATCH(HSTACK("Item",code_for_summary), Table1[#Headers])),2,-1),10)


